# Can a race condition occurs in a delivery app

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

We are developing a web app with Laravel where any customer can create an order to send a package from somewhere to somewhere else.  Then the people who are registered as couriers in the system can see the list of orders and take charge of delivering a package if they wish.  We had a discussion in the team that if there are a large number of orders and couriers, there may be a race condition when the courier wants to accept an order.

We have an order table and a couriers table, and when a courier accepts an order, we set the courier_id column of that specific order. Of course we check if courier_id is null before setting it by a new value.

What Do you think about it? Is there any chance to occurs a race condition? And how we can avoid it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a race condition as long as

1. The customer can only save a valid entry in the orders table
2. Or there is a flag in the orders table that the customer sets to say that they have finished entering all the details.
3. Of course, two couriers could accept the same order at about the same time.

   1. One way to sort this is to lock the order when they view it so only one can accept it.
   2. Or, Both attempt to modify it, but the second one fails (because the update query's where clause has the condition `not accepted` and the query is setting the `accepted` field)